Loose shower arm shreds Teflon tape and causes leak. Is there a better way to seal it?

So I just replaced the shower arm (the old one broke). I wrapped the nipple in Teflon tape, then hand-tightened the new shower arm until it was firmly in place.
At first, it worked perfectly. No leaking.
However, whenever I adjust the shower head, the shower arm rotates in place a little, shredding the Teflon tape and causing a leak. When I removed the shower arm to inspect it, I could see strands of shredded Teflon tape hanging down, where the nipple's threads shredded it when the arm was rotated.

The leak stops if I remove the shower head.
Luckily, there is zero leaking on the back end of the pipe inside the wall (it's bone dry back there). It only leaks at the front end.

Am I correct in assuming this means I need to reinstall the shower arm with:

new Teflon tape,
PLUS some type of caulk to lock it firmly in place?

If so, what type of caulk? If not, what should I do instead?
Thank you!

Teflon tape is used on threads that do not move.  If it moves, then not tight enough or those threads do not use tape.  Assuming the tape is put on right.  Tight enough is half way between too loose and too tight.

Hand-tightened is probably not tight enough. Give it another turn with a strap wrench or similar. You could also try liquid pipe thread sealant instead of Teflon tape.

Pipe dope would be the product to look for. but yes, hand tightening Just Won't Do and properly tightening it should keep it from moving when you adjust the shower head.
